# Problem with Facebook apprequests

Tags: php, facebook

sometimes I get empty array as result of API call /me/apperquests after sending request via [request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)
I'm using PHP library from Facebook's PHP SDK, so auth is ok (and for example /me call is ok).

Can somebody help me, why this is happening? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Blind guess : either FB REST API itself is return empty response at the moment or cURL inside the Facebook PHP SDK fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling [`/me/apprequests`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) will return the requests that were *sent to you* from apps and friends **NOT** the requests that *you sent* to others!

> apprequests - The user's outstanding requests from an app.

---

I have suggested a solution to keep track of the requests sent by a user and it's described in depth [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/).

In short, you handle the response of the `apprequests` callback which contains the request ids and store them in your DB along with the user's (sender) id.

**Code:**

```
<?php
// PATH TO THE FB-PHP-SDK
require_once '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET'
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

if ( empty($user) ) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
    exit();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">Send Application Request</a>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : 'APP_ID',
          status  : true,
          cookie  : true,
          xfbml   : true,
          oauth   : true
        });
    };

    $('a').click(sendRequest);
    function sendRequest() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Check out this application!',
            title: 'Send your friends an application request',
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && response.request_ids) {
                var requests = response.request_ids.join(',');
                $.post('handle_requests.php',{uid: <?php echo $user; ?>, request_ids: requests},function(resp) {
                    // do something
                });
            } else {
                alert('canceled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously the PHP-SDK is not really needed.

Comment: You are welcome, I have extended my answer and included a link to my full article on how to send and keep track of a user's request (sent)

Comment: Thank you for example and link! I did it similarly in my app.

Comment: Additional information: Calling `/me/apprequests` with **GET** will return results.